# How to apply between clause on two columns in Linq query while searching from datatable C#?

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2008, datatable

I have table in SQL Server 2008 in which grade criteria is defined and its columns are

```
GradeID, GradeTitle, FromMarks, ToMarks, ClassID
```

and data is populated as

[image]

Then I have another table in which I store marks of different subjects and I need to apply grades on obtained marks.

Here is example...

If student gets 78 % marks then A grade will be assigned to him and if gets 20 % marks then F grade will be assigned.

Before assigning it I pull all grades from database to datatable as

```
DataTable dtgrade = objExmGrades.Select_ClassGrades(Convert.ToInt32(drpClass.SelectedValue));
```

and I got some help form google and manipulate Linq query to approach it

```
 IEnumerable<string> query = from myrow in dtgrade.AsEnumerable() where (myrow.Field<decimal>("FromMarks") <= 40 && myrow.Field<decimal>("ToMarks") >= 40) select myrow.Field<string>("GradeTitle");
```

where 40 is marks % of student here it should return GradeTitle "**D**" but it return empty... its just like `between` `clause` of `sql select command` but I need it in linq

I am new to Linq so I need your help to get out of this....

I am using asp.net C#

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you describe the query that you are trying to build?

Comment: Can you verify that `dtgrade` actually contains the data?

Comment: @YacoubMassad, Yes dtgrade have data.. i confirmed it

Comment: Maybe you did not execute the query? Try `query = query.ToList();`.

Comment: @YacoubMassad, i also did it, .ToList(), and also .Count();......

Comment: Voting to close as a Typo (see answer below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have confused the operators.

You want *between*, so use `>= ... <=` instead of `<= ... >=`:

```
IEnumerable<string> query = 
    from myrow in dtgrade.AsEnumerable() 
    where myrow.Field<decimal>("FromMarks") >= 40 && myrow.Field<decimal>("ToMarks") <= 40 
    select myrow.Field<string>("GradeTitle");
```

But don't you actually want to select all where the mark is between 40 and **50**?

Side note: normally it's better to filter on the database side instead of in memory.

Comment: Sharp.. eh. Spotted it quickly

Comment: There is not a case in the table where `FromMarks >= 40` and `ToMarks <= 40`

Comment: I did it according to your suggestion but again it return empty...

Comment: @TimSchmelter, which one?

Comment: @YacoubMassad: nonsense, of course there is none. I've overlooked that he uses 40 for the min- and max values

Comment: @Waqas: Yacoub is absolutely right, there is no record. I guess you want to get all which are between 40 and 50.

Comment: yes @TimSchmelter, I want that row of  datatable which  are between 40 and 50

Comment: @Waqas: so does it work if you use `where myrow.Field<decimal>("FromMarks") >= 40 && myrow.Field<decimal>("ToMarks") <= 50`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter, Again returing empty... and count = 0...

Comment: @Waqas: i cannot believe that. So `query.Count()` returns 0? You're showing a database screenshot, have you used the debugger to inspect the values in the datatable? Is it what you expect?

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I just clean and build solution then it returns me value.. So your suggestion is working fine now.. Thanks for your precious time and expert suggestions.